Design a PID controller for pH control
I am working on a question where we calculate an optimal dosage using multiple sensor inputs. Then we send the calculated dosage to the plant and monitor the pH value.
Right now we have an open loop system. I want to maintain the output pH value of 5.2 to 5.8 by introducing feedback and a PID controller.
How to convert this open loop system into a closed loop system using a PID?
I have previous data about our calculated dosage and the resulting pH values.

Where is the question? There is no questionmark. Also, there is no actionable information. All I see is a mission statement.

Question is how to convert this open loop system into a closed loop system using a PID?

Then edit your question to reflect that! Anyway i have done this kind of stuff and i think your question is too broad to tackle in any meaninful way. But thats fine its your question. I am just doubting that your not going to be very happy with the high level answer question asked this way will generate. But thats all you can get since your question is essentally so broad.

Can I contact you on this please?

What action do you take to decrease pH if the initial dosage increased pH above level? What action do you take to increase pH if the initial dosage decreased pH below level? What is the plant and its behaviour? Please also tell us exactly where you are stuck. What is your previous experience with PID? The question is too vague / broad.

I will tell you that depending on what your starting ph is, the logarithmic nature of pH makes it extremely difficult to control with a single simple controller.   Multiple mixing tanks make it much easier.  You need a thousand times the acid to neutralize pH 11 vs pH 8.  Multiple input pumps/valves might also work.  Work out how much you will add for your full range of input conditions and you will quickly see the problem.
